# Some other or another

Tags: word-choice, determiners

I wonder if "some other" means exactly the same as "another" in the following sentences. Is there any difference between them?

> 1. - There must be *another* explanation.
>    - There must be *some other* explanation.
> 2. - In this case we will go to *some other* city.
>    - In this case we will go to *another* city.
> 3. - After that they saw *some other* house.
>    - After that they saw *another* house.

Comment: [ODO on *some other*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/other?q=some+other) gives an example and definition which is remarkably similar to [another](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/another?q=another). However *the other* uses the definite article and must refer to something specific. There is no evidence of prior research in this question.

Answer (score 3):

1a is ungrammatical. In the subsequent examples the difference is that *another* is more definite. By using *some other*, the speaker or writer is making a reference so vague that there is some doubt over whether the statement in which it occurs can be true.

Comment: Can it be that: "2) There must be another explanation." - means that there really exists a certain explanation somewhere in the world, while "2a)There must be some other explanation." - means that "some other" explanation is only an assumption, that is, this explanation hasn't been revealed or materialized in someone's mind yet but hypothetically it might come along in the future. Is such an explanation probable? –

Comment: @user1425. Yes, something on those lines, I would say.